# Java Interface with Inheritance

Tags: java, generics

I'm looking for assistance on how to implement this Repository. Here's what I have so far:

```
public interface IEntity {
    int getId(); //would rather not depend on int. fix later.
}

public interface IRepository<T extends IEntity> {

    Collection<T> findAll();
    T find(T t);
    T findById(int id); //would rather not depend on int. fix later.
    void add(T t);
    void remove(T t);
}

public interface ISurveyRepository extends IRepository<Survey> {

}
```

The problem I'm running into is that I need for `T` in the `IRepository` signature to extend `IEntity`, but I don't need `IRepository` in the `ISurveyRepository` signature to have a bounded type parameter. I would like for the signature to just be

```
public interface ISurveyRepository extends IRepository { }
```

so that I could create a concrete class that just implements `ISurveyRepository`

```
public class MySurveyRepository extends ISurveyRepository { }
```

How can I go about doing that?

Comment: What exactly is the reason that you don't want to extend `IRepository` with the type parameter? Note that you don't implement an interface by `extends`, but by `implements`.

Comment: Why does your `IRepository` extend `IEntity`?

Comment: IMO `Survey` should implement `IEntity`.

Comment: @BalusC My initial thinking was that if I made IRepository without the type parameter then it would be more generic (I wouldn't have to put a class in the placeholder). After you asked the question I thought about it and it seems to make sense to leave the typed parameter there because then I can just my Survey class in the placeholder. Any thoughts?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz That was a typo from an older file that I copied from. I've removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do better than this.

Fix that `int` problem now.  Use a generic DAO interface, like this:

```
public interface Repository<T, K extends Serializable> {
    List<T> find();
    T find(K id);
    K save(T value);
    void update(T value);
    void delete(T value);    
}
```

Lose that Hungarian notation in disguise: no "I" for "interface".

You can write a generic implementation, too.

Comment: K save(T value) is unlikely to work.  You can not execute new K.

Comment: @duffymo why did you use List<T> instead of Collection<T>?

Comment: K is the key that you return.  What do you mean "can't execute new K"?

Comment: Why not?  What's wrong with List<T>?  I find Collection<T> to be too restrictive.  Both are interfaces.  That was the decision I made when I created it.

Comment: As far as recommendations for improving your code, this contains a lot of good information - my answer was restricted to the exact specified domain.

Comment: Give the best answer - it's not always about sticking to a narrow domain.  Other people might come back months from now and benefit from a wider view.  Give it when you can.

Comment: @duffymo I was curious to see why you used it as I'm a beginner and I thought I'd ask the question. I honestly don't know the answer to your "why not?" question I just thought I'd ask. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize where you were coming from.  I prefer List to Collection because it provides random access to elements using the get() method.  With Collection, you have to iterate.  I find it less convenient most of the time.  But your point is well taken: there might be an advantage in using an interface that's higher in the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a class like:

```
public class MySurveyRepository extends ISurveyRepository {}
```

Then your existing interface (with the use of generics) will do just fine.  Your implementing class will 'inherit' the definition by design, and will be (effecticely) completely unaware that it's descended from a previously-generic interface.

If you're using one of the modern editors, like Eclipse, to write your code, when you ask it to fill in the missing inherited methods it won't give you `T` - it'll give you `Survey`.